# WebView continues to request data even after onPause is called

Tags: android, webview

The documentation for [onPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onPause()) suggests that it will prevent an Android WebView instance from downloading data. This does not appear to be the case on the Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1. See test app [here](https://github.com/alexbirkett/WebViewIssue)

Is there a workaround for this problem that does not involve calling [pauseTimers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pauseTimers()) which pauses timers for all WebViews?

The data requests were observed using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

The web view was set to load http://live.tv2.no/monika-saken?mode=app

Comment: The issue can also be reproduced on a Nextbit Robin running Android 6.0.1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? `pauseTimers` is not good because it applies to all WebViews.